# Output in one column from multiple input in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem to put the input from user in one line separate by comma.
As below code:

```
<table width="691" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><%do while not rs2.EOF%>
  <td width="159" rowspan="2" class="commontextBold">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="200" rowspan="2" class="commontextBold">&nbsp;</td>
  <td>
  <span class="commontextBold"><%=rs2.fields("do1").value%>
  <%      rs2.movenext    
  loop%>
  </span>
  </td>
```

From line 5 to 10, that is the code using to print the output.
For this code the output will looks like (as can see in attachment image):

1111111 -space- 2222222 : this output look like when using loop it will give to much space between the output

I need the output looks like this,

1111111,2222222

The output may be more that two, depend on user input.
How can i avoid the output print without too many spaces between the value?
FYI, this output will be print in the courier slip.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MysN.jpg)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19xLY.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure if this is want you want:

```
<table width="691" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td width="159" rowspan="2" class="commontextBold">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="200" rowspan="2" class="commontextBold">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <%do while not rs2.EOF%>
        <span class="commontextBold"><%=rs2.fields("do1").value%></span>
        <%rs2.movenext    
        loop%>
    </td>
```